# Time profiler on device not the same with simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, instruments, xcode4.6

I have a strange problem when running Time Profiler on device, the result is not the same with  simulator.

This is the screenshot from simulator:
[image]

In this I can see the method, thread, and can find out the problem with my code.

But on the screenshot from device:
[image]

The sample tree in this screenshot does not contain information about method, thread. This is useless for me.

I am using XCode 4.6.3

Anyone have this problem before? I am very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I see this often. My workaround has been to run the profiler against a debug version instead of a release version. But I'd like to know a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on the simulator. As it says, it `simulates` the device. Only consider tests on the device (try on several devices to be sure about the results).

EDIT:

About not showing the calls in the device, it's probably because you're using a build different configuration to run on the simulator and on the device. Check if `COPY_PHASE_STRIP` is set to `NO` in all build configurations on your target's build settings.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about why symbols don't show up when running on the device.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That's why I would like to run Time Profiler on device. But the result I get is just memory pointer. This is useless.

Comment: Still have problem. But when I follow rmaddy above, change /Edit Scheme/Profile/Build Configuration from Release to Debug. It works. I think maybe the reason is Time Profiler will only catch memory pointer when running with release.